# Is turning input and label into block level items okey?

Tags: html, wordpress, block, inline, semantics

I know that you can't (semantically) do something like:

```
<p>
    <div> Lorem... </div>
</p>
```

I am working on the comment_form() for WordPress:

```
<form...>
<div<
    <label>Label<label><input...>
</div>
...
</form>
```

I am using Foundation's mixin's (sass) to set a grid to label and input. This mixin will make the label and input a block (those are normally a inline). Is this, okey? Should I put the label and input in 2 different div's again and set the grid mixins on those instead?

What I also found in the default comment_form() function is:

```
<p class="form-submit">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['id_submit'] ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $args['label_submit'] ); ?>" />
    <?php comment_id_fields( $post_id ); ?>
</p>
```

Because I can't change that p to a div I probably have to recreate the hole function. I think I need to do this because Foundation will set the display to block for the input submit. Should I leave it as is or if I want semantic markup, should I recreate the function?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with setting the display property value for label and anchor to "block". There is less mark up in this case and it's more semantic than nesting them in div elements.

This will also help make your layout scalable. If you nest them in a block level element and decide later you want to change the layout, you will have to update the markup rather than making an adjustment to the CSS.